# GraphQL и Spring Boot: нельзя зарегистрировать компонент Query, запросы не вополняются

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

Я хочу разобраться в том, как выполнять запросы к API на спринг буте, в котором используется GraphQL. У меня есть такой небольшой проект:

`pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>GraphQL</groupId>
    <artifactId>GraphQL</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.6.v20170531</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

`Application.java`:

```
package aoizora;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

`Pet.java`:

```
package aoizora.entities;

import aoizora.enums.Animal;

public class Pet {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private Animal type;
    private int age;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Animal getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Animal type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

`Animal.java`:

```
package aoizora.enums;

public enum Animal {
    GOD,
    CAT,
    BADGER,
    MAMMOTH
}
```

`Query resolver`:

```
package aoizora.resolvers;

import aoizora.enums.Animal;
import aoizora.entities.Pet;
import com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.GraphQLQueryResolver;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Query implements GraphQLQueryResolver {

    public List<Pet> pets() {
        List<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<>();

        Pet aPet = new Pet();
        aPet.setId(1l);
        aPet.setName("Bill");
        aPet.setAge(9);
        aPet.setType(Animal.MAMMOTH);

        pets.add(aPet);

        return pets;
    }
}
```

И сама схема:

```
type Query {
    pets: [Pet]
}

type Pet {
    id: Int
    type: Animal
    name: String
    age: String
}

enum Animal {
    DOG
    CAT
    BADGER
    MAMMOTH
}
```

Проблема такова: сделать запрос не получается и непонятно, как использовать класс Query. В примере, по которому я изучаю `GraphQL`, класс Query отмечен аннотацией @Component, но если я применю ее к классу Query, то приложение не стартует и падает с ошибкой "невозможно зарегистрировать бин". Если аннотацию убрать, то приложение запускается, но выполнять запросы все равно невозможно.

Как правильно сконфигурировать этот проект, чтобы все работало?